# Entropy of Black Hole

Tags: black-holes, entropy, black-hole-thermodynamics

What is the relation between the entropy of rotating and non rotating Black hole? Which one has greater entropy?

Answer (score 4):

The entropy of a black hole is given by the area $A$ of its event horizon according to the formula $S=\frac{kA}{4l_P}$ where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant and $l_P$ is the Planck length.

For a rotating black hole with mass $M$ and a Kerr parameter $a$ the area is $A=\frac{8\pi G^2}{c^4}M(M+\sqrt{M^2-a^2})$. This is largest when $a=0$ corresponding to the non-rotating case. so the rotating black hole has less entropy than a static black hole of the same mass.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate entropy of a black hole by dividing its surface area with planck length.
You can read more about black hole entropy here:http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy